# How to get my assigned cell "Pathname" to open the master copy it is generated from. The information in the cell is accurate when generated

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a "Master File" that generates a "field-generated" copy that at the push of a button is supposed to open the Master File and copy data back to it. The Field copy has a cell "ZZ1000" that has been titled "Pathname". When the field copy is generated the "Pathname" cell is filled out with the location of the master file. I have triple checked the "Pathname" is accurate, but when I hit the button I am receiving Run-time error '1004 Couldn't find the file.... However, during this it will still open the file, but will not allow the two files to communicate. When I debug this the third line highlight "Workbook.open" what can I do to avoid this? I am still fairly new to VBA so my trouble shooting skills are minimal at this point. Any direction would be appreciated.

```
Sub OpenWorkbook()
'Open a workbook

`'Open method requires full file path to be referenced.


  Dim Pathname As String
  Pathname = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Field Copy").Range("Pathname").Formula
  Workbooks.Open Pathname
  ThisWorkbook.Unprotect "cost"
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Field Copy").Visible = True
  ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Field Copy").Visible = False
  ThisWorkbook.Protect "cost"
With ActiveWorkbook
Workbooks("Field Copy.xlsx").Worksheets("Field Copy").Range("H5:BU52").Copy _
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Field Copy").Range("H5")

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try `.Text` instead of `.Formula` as the latter is specifically for the Excel formula in the cell, not the cells' value

Comment: Is the cell filled with the *path* or the *fullname* of the master file? Is the master already open? Have you checked the content of the variable `Pathname` in the debugger when the error occurs? You can enter `? Dir(Pathname)` in the immediate window of the debugger to check if the file exists

Comment: Thank you all, I ended up correct it by link a command button as opposed to a standard button I appreciate everyone's help.